# Sending UDP packets from the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, udp

Does anyone have any good tutorials on sending UDP packets from the iPhone SDK?

EDIT:

Was actually really easy to do this...

*RTFM!*

After including AsyncUdpSocket just add this in header:

```
AsyncUdpSocket *socket;
```

And in main:

```
NSData *data = ... 
[socket sendData:data toHost:@"192.168.x.x" port:5002 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

When testing don't forget to allow UDP communication on your server firewall!

Comment: A bit of history ... at one stage there was the absolutely INCREDIBLE AsyncSocket library, originally created by the mysterious Dustin J. Voss. (sometimes known as CocoaAsyncSocket.) At one point it came with easy UDP example code and it was central to iOS development.  Probably still valuable if you can dig it up. It was an incredible library.

Comment: how to handle if the IP address varies

Comment: @Cyph3r You would need to use some custom logic to set a `NSString` variable, which you can pass in the `toHost` param. Or, alternatively use a domain and setup a DNS record instead of using the IP address and update that where necessary. It completely depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) is a nice library that contains a class called `AsyncUdpSocket` which is an Obj-C wrapper around the lower-level socket API.

Comment: I'll give you correct answer as you got me on the way! For anyone reading this question with same issue I posted some code as a edit in the question.

Comment: Link updated to what appears to be its new home on github: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CFNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Concepts/Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH4-SW13) framwork to create a UDP socket with CFSocket. Here is the [CFSocket reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001445).

Comment: So to send a UDP packet to my server do I just use CFSocketSendData?

Comment: Yes, after you CFSocketCreate with IPPROTO_UDP, you can use CFSocketSendData. The Mac Network Programming mailing list is a good place to find examples: http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/

Comment: AsyncUdpSocket was much more simple! :)